# to print the variable values in python in debug mode ( pycharm is the IDE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I want to print the value of variable on the pycharm console while in the debug mode in python. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can switch between debugger and console. Also, you need to put breakpoints where you need debugger to stop.

Comment: yeah, i have put a debug point on the line, where i have to examine the value of the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug mode in PyCharm has two sections, **debugger** and **console**:

[image]

Debug shows you the variables in memory, and console shows the output of your code. Additionally, if you're at a breakpoint you can print variables out or interact with them in the **debug console**. Click on the second-last icon here 
[image] 
 while in debug mode. (If you don't see it, try enlarging the bottom debugging area upwards.)

If you still can't find it, look for a console icon on the top right - sometimes the console gets hidden for some reason.